# Java - is one file path part of another?

Tags: java, file

I am wondering if there is a quick simple way to check whether a file path comes under another path. For example, given C:\Fruit\Apple\Core, I want to test it against a list of files, which contains C:\Fruit\Apple, and be able to tell that it is contained within that path.

Just writing this question it occurs to me that I can simply compare the substring of the longer file against the current file.

So what I'd like to know now, is there any way to do this with File objects? Or would it still be easier to get the string version of each path and compare as above. (I am still using java 1.6 so cannot use java.nio.Path;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string1.startsWith(string2)` is still easiest.

Comment: Indeed, why make a simple problem hard! Thanks

Comment: :) Just be sure to have the directory end with a slash, otherwise you'll match on `C:\Fruit\AppleJuice`, too.

Comment: This might be a problem if there are symbolic links and you want to take them into account. But I'm guessing from the acceptance this isn't a problem.

Comment: This can (and thus will) break.  Counter-example: `/usr/someuser/apple` and `/usr/someuser/applejuice/`.  or if you prefer, for Windows: `C:\Users\SomeUser\Apple` `C:\Users\SomeUser\AppleJuice`.  If `Apple` is a filename without an extension (common in the Unix case, possible in the Windows case), then you can't simply add a path separator character to the end to solve the problem.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: You misunderstand: I proposed adding the slash to the *shorter* file. `/usr/someuser/apple/` will match `/usr/someuser/apple/juice`, but not `/usr/someuser/applejuice`.

Comment: Given the path `/usr/someuser/apple`, if it is a directory, then you're fine.  But if it is a file, then you can't simply add a slash to it.  The OP talked about files, and never said they could be guaranteed that both path names would end in directories.  That may be their case, in which case they should clarify this in the question.  But with the question as asked, and your answer as given, the answer can break.

Comment: If the shorter path isn't a directory, I don't see any purpose to the question, nor do I see a way to interpret the phrase "contained within that path". You can't contain some file within a file, unless it's an archive, but that is clearly not what OP meant. Of course it's a directory.

Comment: I am only looking to be using directories for this particular check. The basis of the idea is to make sure that the directory has not already been checked. It can be assumed that they will all be directory and while I don't have my code on hand I believe somewhere before I check the actual `File` object to make sure it's a directoy before comparing string paths.